# Problem with calculation of the norm of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

It is known that $\vec{u} [3,4]$ and $\vec{v}[2,k]$. And I need to find k such that the norm of the projection of ⃗  over ⃗  equals to 1.

I am trying to obtain the norm of the vector $\frac{6+4k}{25} \vec{u}$.

However, the answer key tells me that the norm would be $\frac{|6+4k|}{5}$

But I am not sure what to do in order to obtain such an answer?

Comment: What do you know about $\overrightarrow{u}$ and $k$?

Comment: @Gribouillis I just edited the question, sorry for not making it clear before

Answer (score 2):

$$\Big\| \frac{6+4k}{25} u\Big\| = \frac{|6+4k|}{25}\|u\| = \frac{|6+4k|}{25}\sqrt{3^2+4^2} = \frac{|6+4k|}{5}$$

Comment: Oh okay, thanks I understand now! My mind was not thinking clear